# Why are writes so slow on ext4?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, performance, ext4

I'm trying to work out why writing to ext4 partitions on my server is so slow. I noticed this issue when I reformatted my off-site backup drives from ExFAT to ext4. When these drives were formatted as ExFAT, I was seeing write speeds around 140-150MB/s. Now, with the same drives formatted at ext4, I'm seeing write speeds of around 40MB/s.

The two drives are 4TB Western Digital Elements Portable (25A1) drives, connected over USB 3.

I've made sure the the ext4 lazy init has finished before running any benchmarking.

Here's the output of `findmnt --target` for one of the drives:

```
TARGET          SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/off-site_2 /dev/sdd1 ext4   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime
```

Other info (some duplicated from comments for convenience):

- I'm rsyncing many family large (1GB-5GB) files to these drives.
- All files are smaller than the amount of available memory.
- This system has 8GB of RAM installed and normally less than 512mb in use; the rest used by cache.
- The `Dirty` value in `/proc/meminfo` floats up to around 1.3GB when writing data to the drives, regardless of whether the FS is ExFAT or ext4.
- Kernel is `4.19.0-11-amd64` which is the latest available to me right now on Debian 10.
- The model of the drives is WDC WD40NMZW-11GX6S1. According to [this](https://hddscan.com/blog/2020/hdd-wd-smr.html), it's an SMR drive.
- The output of `dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdd1`

```
root@Server:~# dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdd1
dumpe2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Filesystem volume name:   Off-site 2
Last mounted on:          /mnt/off-site_2
Filesystem UUID:          d5f29945-6e3c-45d1-98bb-ac2dd404975a
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              244187136
Block count:              976745979
Reserved block count:     48837298
Free blocks:              83988236
Free inodes:              244182173
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Mon Oct  5 15:47:31 2020
Last mount time:          Wed Oct  7 20:09:00 2020
Last write time:          Wed Oct  7 20:32:22 2020
Mount count:              6
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Mon Oct  5 15:47:31 2020
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          3433 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      777766d4-df04-4c2c-b503-f7244bf87810
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0xbf1db7ae
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke journal_64bit journal_checksum_v3
Journal size:             1024M
Journal length:           262144
Journal sequence:         0x00003fdd
Journal start:            0
Journal checksum type:    crc32c
Journal checksum:         0x2a21e235
```

I've attempted to demonstrate the issue here:

```
# ExFAT drive
root@Server:/mnt/off-site_1/test# dd if=/dev/zero of=test.bin bs=1M count=5000 status=progress
5131730944 bytes (5.1 GB, 4.8 GiB) copied, 23 s, 223 MB/s
5000+0 records in
5000+0 records out
5242880000 bytes (5.2 GB, 4.9 GiB) copied, 23.6661 s, 222 MB/s

# ext4 drive
root@Server:/mnt/off-site_2/test# dd if=/dev/zero of=test.bin bs=1M count=5000 status=progress
5173673984 bytes (5.2 GB, 4.8 GiB) copied, 44 s, 118 MB/s
5000+0 records in
5000+0 records out
5242880000 bytes (5.2 GB, 4.9 GiB) copied, 58.9746 s, 88.9 MB/s
```

Comment: post the result of `findmnt --target «path to mount-point»`

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I've just added the output of that command to the answer

Comment: Are these sustained writes that are larger than available memory, and/or does the measurement time include the synchronisation during `umount`? USB drives are generally configured with write-back caches, and the FAT family of file systems doesn't enforce ordering of writes properly on these, while ext4 does. I'd keep a terminal open with `watch cat /proc/meminfo`, and see how the `Dirty` value changes during the performance tests -- my expectation would be that exFAT generates lots of buffers and reports completion, while ext4 only submits data buffers after metadata is reported written.

Comment: @SimonRichter I'm rsyncing many family large (1GB-5GB) files to these drives, so yes, I guess you could class that as sustained writes. Larger than available memory? I think all files are smaller than the amount of available memory. This system has 8GB of RAM installed and normally less than 512mb in use; the rest used by cache. The `Dirty` value in `/proc/meminfo` floats up to around 1.3GB when writing data to the drives, regardless of whether the FS is ExFAT or ext4.

Comment: What are the model numbers of the disks (specifically are they SMR or CMR disks)?

Comment: What kernel version is in use (`uname -r`)?  Which filesystem features are enabled (`dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdd1` will show this along with other filesystem parameters)?

Comment: @roaima According to `parted`: `Model: WD Elements 25A1 (scsi)`. I can't seem to find any information on whether the drive is SMR or not. I'd be surprised as it was my understanding that the SMR topic was restricted to WD 3.5" NAS drives and this is a 2.5" portable USB drive. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @LustreOne The kernel is `4.19.0-11-amd64` and that's the latest version available to me via the normal channels on Debian 10. I've added the output of `dumpe2fs -h /dev/sdd1` to the question.

Comment: You'd need the model number of the disk itself. SMART should be able to provide that. But if you're comfortable it's not an SMR/CMR issue I'll back out.

Comment: @roaima The model of the drives is `WDC WD40NMZW-11GX6S1`. According to [this](https://hddscan.com/blog/2020/hdd-wd-smr.html), it's an SMR drive.

Comment: OK. Was just a thought. Good to hear it's SMR though